# css - style the edge of the selected area in table

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a selectable table (jQuery UI selectable). How do i "access" the edge (top, left, right, bottom) width css, or do I have to use javascript?

*Update:* with "accessing the edge" I mean for example create a border around a selected area in a table (select td elements, first .ui-selected in tr, last .ui-selected in tr, first tr containing .ui-selected, last tr containing .ui-selected).

```
<table class="ui-selectable">
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee ui-selected"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee ui-selected"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee ui-selected"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee ui-selected"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
        <td class="ui-selectee"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ex: the left edge

```
.ui-selected {
    border-left: 1px solid #00F;
}
.ui-selected ~ .ui-selected {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate about "accessing the edge"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left:

```
td:first-child
```

Right:

```
td:last-child
```

Top:

```
tr:first-child td
```

Bottom:

```
tr:last-child td
```

*Edit:* with your updates, I can now state that there is no way to do it in CSS3. But CSS4's `:nth-match` and `:nth-last-match` (not implemented anywhere at the time of writing, and the spec is only a working draft) will be able to do it.